# in Sonatype Nexus OSS, snapshot versions of rpm are not available for yum

Tags: maven, rpm, nexus, sonatype

We deploy rpm's to Nexus as maven artifacts, we enable yum repositories as per the documentation.
when we run

```
yum list available MY-APP --showduplicates
```

Release versions of the rpm's are ok and available to yum.
but snapshot versions are not. sometimes the snapshot repo takes a long time to load and yum fails on timeout. sometimes it doesn't fail but we only see release versions and not snapshots.
trying to run the scheduled task of snapshots it takes forever and nothing happens. and couldn't find a clue in the nexus logs.
I must say that our repository is large and has thousands of snapshots of various projects.

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1):

The YUM integration of Nexus supports SNAPSHOT repositories just fine. I suggest you upgrade your Nexus instance to the latest version of Nexus 2 so you gain access to some performance enhancements for the related scheduled tasks.

Then you need to use them and ensure that the snapshot repository is trimmed in size to a level where createrepo and yum don't die. You might also want to consider upgrading the server itself to a higher performance setup. This is not really a Nexus issue but more a yum/createrepo performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers.
I deleted the repodata folder in nexus repository and it started working again.

Answer (score -1):

I assume what is taking so long is the *'createrepo'* command, I haven't used the Nexus yum plugin since I am using Artifactory which worked after 2 min of configuration with no issues ...
Bust considering you mentioned the repo is hugh with tons of SNAPSHOTS I assume that the *createrepo* implementation is just constantly running or stuck - I would suggest having smaller yum repositories (per version / pre release / per component etc) which will probably solve your issue { or you can tryout Artifactory ... and no I don't work there ;)}